# create iteratively multi index and multi columns dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let's say that I want to create a multi index and multi column dataframe:

```
                          X         Y
Planet Continent Country  A    B    C     D 
Earth     Europe England  0.3  0.5  0.6   0.8
          Europe Italy    0.1  0.2  0.4   1.2 
Mars      Tempe  Sirtys   3.2  4.5  2.3   4.2
```

I want to do that by iteratively collecting each single row of the dataframe,

```
row1 =  np.array(['Earth', 'Europe', 'England', 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8])
row2 =  np.array(['Earth', 'Europe', 'Italy', 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 1.2])
```

I know how, starting with rows, I can create a multi-column dataframe, and I know how I can create a multi-index one. But how can I create both?
Thanks

Comment: df.reset_index().to_numpy() ?

Comment: how do you start? do you already have the multiindex index and columns in an empty dataframe?

Comment: I think OP wants to go in the other direction.

Comment: I can start in any way to be honest. What's important is that at some point I have those rows and I need to build a dataframe out of it, using the first x element as indexes and the other as values in a multi-columns fashion.
Also yes, I want to go from numpy to pandas :)
Edit: Ben, if I understand you question, I have the column names and the multi indexes names, not all the possible indexes.

Comment: It also depends on how you want/need to create your dataframe. Do you need to update the rows one-by-one? Or do you have all the rows and want to create the dataframe at once?

Comment: I can collect a bunch of rows in a chunk and create a dataframe, but they will not include *all* possible indexes. I may able to do that if necessary though

Comment: Will your row always be the same shape? i.e., 3 index values, 4 X/Y ABCD values? Honestly I'm of the opinion create the final frame before setting the multi index, but I digress.

Comment: r.ook, yes, same shape

Comment: @Vaaal88 are you lookg to just create the frame and set the index `df = pd.DataFrame([row1, row2]).set_index([0,1,2])` and then assign the multiindex column `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('X', 'A'), ('X', 'B'), ('Y', 'C'), ('Y', 'D')])`? You can assign the index names as well...`df.index.names = ['Planet', 'Continent', 'Country']`

Comment: YES! I was missing the last bit, I didn't think you could assign to column in that way! Please write it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
row1 =  np.array(['Earth', 'Europe', 'England', 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8])
row2 =  np.array(['Earth', 'Europe', 'Italy', 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 1.2])
# create a data frame and set index
df = pd.DataFrame([row1, row2]).set_index([0,1,2])
# set the index names
df.index.names = ['Planet', 'Continent', 'Country']
# create a multi-index and assign to columns
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('X', 'A'), ('X', 'B'), ('Y', 'C'), ('Y', 'D')])

                            X         Y     
                            A    B    C    D
Planet Continent Country                    
Earth  Europe    England  0.3  0.5  0.6  0.8
                 Italy    0.1  0.2  0.4  1.2
```

Comment: Both answers are great, but this fits perfectly with how my code was designed already. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

if you start from an empty dataframe define with multiindex index and columns (as known according to you):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[]]*3, 
                                      codes=[[]]*3, 
                                      names=['Planet','Continent','Country']), 
                 columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('X','A'), ('X','B'),
                                                    ('Y','C'), ('Y', 'D')],))
```

Then you can just add each row like:

```
df.loc[tuple(row1[:3]), :]= row1[3:]
print (df)
                            X         Y     
                            A    B    C    D
Planet Continent Country                    
Earth  Europe    England  0.3  0.5  0.6  0.8
```

and again after:

```
df.loc[tuple(row2[:3]), :]= row2[3:]
print (df)
                            X         Y     
                            A    B    C    D
Planet Continent Country                    
Earth  Europe    England  0.3  0.5  0.6  0.8
                 Italy    0.1  0.2  0.4  1.2
```

but if you have a lot of rows available at once, the answer of [@Yo_Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61503436/9274732) will be way more easy

Comment: I chose the other one as it matched better with how my code was already structured. Thanks nonetheless!